# Concealing PEX indoors with a metal hat channel

Tags: plumbing, installation, pex

I'm replacing the galvanized incoming cold line with PEX.  The incoming line runs into the exterior wall of the home about a foot from the ground, then goes down the wall, through the sill plate into the slab.  We discovered a leak in part of it under the slab in the adjacent bathroom; that's what's leading to this replacement.

Where the cold line comes in is in a lower cabinet unit next to the kitchen sink cabinet.  I have a hole in the plaster, exposing the incoming galvanized.  I'd like to do a transition to PEX, and then run it on the back wall inside the cabinets over to the kitchen sink, about 2 1/2 feet. Obviously, I'd rather do this than either run plumbing outside the hous, or tear open the entire wall under these kitchen cabinets.  It is totally dark under there, so I don't think UV exposure is an issue.

To keep anyone from damaging it, I was thinking of covering it with a metal hat channel like this one: [7/8" metal hat channel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Super-Stud-Building-Products-7-8-in-x-10-ft-25-Gauge-Galvanized-Steel-Furring-Channel-78100/202093381?keyword=metal%20hat%20channel&semanticToken=oos%3A%7B0%3A1%7D)

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks for your thoughts!